# Modifying Elements in a Matrix - R

Tags: r, matrix

**My Code:**

```
#the first few lines are supposed to help reproduce the code if needed.
world_rank <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
quality_of_education <- c(1, 9, 3, 2, 7, 13)
influence <- c(1, 3, 2, 6, 12, 13)
broad_impact <- c(1, 4, 2, 13, 9, 12)
patents <- c(3, 10, 1, 48, 15, 4)
university_matrix <- cbind(world_rank, quality_of_education, influence, broad_impact, patents)
rownames(university_matrix) <- c("harvard", "stanford", "MIT", "cambridge", "oxford", "Columbia")
usa_universities <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
university_matrix[4,5] <- 3

#the following line is the actual problem.

university_matrix[usa_universities, "world_rank"] <- 2
```

**What I expected to happen:**
Specifically the last line. The line is supposed to " Replace all rankings for the USA’s universities (i.e., Harvard, Stanford, MIT, and Columbia) by 2. I tried this in R studio and it can produce the expected outcome which is a matrix with the world_rank column for harvard, stanford, mit and columbia to be 2.

This is the expected matrix: (formatting is off because of this interface)

```
world_rank quality_of_education influence broad_impact patents
harvard   2 1   1  1  3
stanford  2 9   3  4 10
MIT       2 3   2  2  1
cambridge 4 2   6 13  3
oxford    5 7  12  9 15
columbia  2 13 13 12  4
```

**What actually happened:**
Picture of the output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NU2jIiH1OvTPB16h5AvCCI-UlJ-sLq02/view?usp=sharing
#comment from DataQuest
The rankings for the USA's universities should be 2.

**Question:**
What have I done wrong here? The output of Data quest looks the same as R studio.
Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong here either.  It seems like your problem is with DataQuest?

Comment: The quest might be to replace **all** rankings (not only `world_rank`) with 2.

Comment: then your expected matrix is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all rankings by `2`, then don't specify the column - so that all columns are "meant":

```
university_matrix[usa_universities, ] <- 2

university_matrix
          world_rank quality_of_education influence broad_impact patents
harvard            2                    2         2            2       2
stanford           2                    2         2            2       2
MIT                2                    2         2            2       2
cambridge          4                    2         6           13       3
oxford             5                    7        12            9      15
Columbia           2                    2         2            2       2
```

Alternatively, you can also explicitely list all columns:

```
university_matrix[usa_universities, colnames(university_matrix)] <- 2
# which is the same like:
university_matrix[usa_universities, c("world_rank", "quality_of_education", "influence", "broad_impact", "patents")] <- 2
# which is the above proposed:
university_matrix[usa_universities, ] <- 2
```